# Dirichlet Convolution involving mobius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show the sum
$$\sum_{d/n}|\mu(d)|\mu(\frac{n}{d})$$
only has a result not $0$ when $n$ is a perfect square (and then it's $\mu(\sqrt n)$. I think it might have something to do with perfect squares having an odd number of divisors because $d=n/d$, but I don't know how to use that to prove it?

Comment: Have you used Dirichlet generating series before?  There's a straightforward proof using them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly easy observation with standard Dirichlet series and Euler products:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^s}=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right), \qquad \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right) $$

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{d\mid n}|\mu(d)|\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^s}\right]\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}\right]$$

$$=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2s}}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2s}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicative arithmetic functions ($\gcd(a,b)=1\Rightarrow f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$) are closed under the operation of Dirichlet convolution. In particular $\mu$ and $|\mu|$ are multiplicative. If $n=p^k$ then

$$\sum_{\large d\mid n}|\mu(d)|\mu(n/d)=\sum_{e=0}^k |\mu(p^e)|\mu(p^{k-e})=\begin{cases} 0  & k\ge3 \\ -1 & k=2 \\ 0 & k=1 \\ +1 & k=0\end{cases}$$

The desired conclusion follows.